# How can I get an rss feed of the activity of all my friends on Facebook (updates, shares, etc.)?

Tags: facebook, rss

I've noticed that when I look at the news feeds in facebook, it doesn't show updates from all of my friends. Is there a way to get an rss feed that contains status updates (and possibly shared links) posted by ALL of my friends? Or do I need to create a separate feed for each friend (not feasible.)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't offer an RSS feed but you may use a service like NutshellMail to get all the Facebook updates in an email newsletter. Pass this newsletter to FeedMyInbox.com and there you have an RSS feed of all your updates.

Comment: Thanks. From what I can see, though, NutshellMail only gets the activity that Facebook already shows in the newsfeed. The problem is, the newsfeed isn't complete. A friend had a baby last month, and although she posted an update, it never showed up in my newsfeed. The only way I found out was I went directly to her page because I thought it was strange that she HADN'T posted an update.

Answer (score 0):

facebook limits the number of your friends that get shown in your newsfeed, you need to click the edit options at the bottom of your "most recent" feed page, and edit the number of friends that get shown in your feed.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue; the default setting on mine is 250 friends, and I have fewer than that total, so shouldn't they all be showing?